# Is there any difference of these two git commands?

Tags: git, github

If there is a existing branch called `branch-A` on github (so it is remote), and I want to create my local branch to track that remote branch, I find there are two ways:

first one,

```
git checkout -b branch-A
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch-A
```

the second one:

```
git checkout -b branch-A origin/branch-A
```

I find both ones are working. is there any difference?

thanks

Comment: The second one is a just a shortcut for the first one, at least, there is another shortcut : `git checkout --track -b origin/branch-A`

Comment: They are the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout --track -b branch-A origin/branch-A
```

performs all of the actions

```
git checkout --detach origin/branch-A
git checkout -b branch-A
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch-A
```

in a single command.

When `git config branch.autoSetupMerge true` (default) or `git config branch.autoSetupMerge always`,

```
git checkout -b branch-A origin/branch-A
```

automatically adds the `--track` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I need to tell you that

```
git checkout -b branch-A origin/branch-A
```

or another alias, is the same of

```
git checkout branch-A
```

This because `git checkout -b` create a branch locally and automatically checkout on it. When you push the branch on origin, origin/branch-A will be created. This means that the results is the same, but with less commands.